# How can we get the coverage of automation scripts in terms of HTML elements on UI being accessed. Is there any tool available for this?

Tags: selenium, test-coverage

I have written the test automation scripts in selenium for a website. Along with this I have added JaCOCO scripts to get the code coverage of the application. Now, I want the coverage of the html elements on UI i.e. the list of elements (buttons, text fields, text area, links, drop-downs etc.) which are skipped/covered through the automation. How can we find which elements on a web page are not accessed/tested by the automation scripts, in other words, the UI coverage? Is there any tool for this?

Comment: You are missing the purpose of an e2e test. At this level, the coverage has a meaning only when it's measured against the expected features / use cases.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @FlorentB., specifically I need to know if its possible to get the list of untouched elements on the UI so that I can add more test cases in my scenarios to cover them as well. Sometimes it is hard to keep track of the elements which loads on the page dynamically based on the UI interactions. Also, its hard to cover all the aspects of it which sometimes does not reflect in the code coverage i.e. the validations of non required fields which sometimes we skip in the test implementations.